# Delay initializing a reference - what to initialize with?

Tags: c++, reference

I have a class, which I wish instantiated at a later point of initialization of the program. I definitely don't want any instances of that class before that point. I want this instance to be available in global scope.

The easiest approach would be to have a global variable which is a reference to that class, which is easy enough - just assign the reference right after the class is instantiated. Except I need to fill that reference with *something* until that time, or I'm getting *declared as reference but not initialized*, and I'd rather not create dummy instances of said class.

What would be the right approach to get it working?

```
    configClass&  global_config;   // = ?


    init()
    {
       //... other prerequisites for loading the config
       static configClass _cfg(CONFIG_FILE,other_params);
       global_config = _cfg;
       //more code, using global_config
    }
```

Comment: You cannot make the reference refer to a different object to the one it was created with. You need a different approach. Perhaps a pointer? Or a function with a static member.

Comment: `I want this instance to be available in global scope` Why's that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Because it's used in thousands upon thousands places across all the code and obscuring it behind any namespace or something like this would be immensely counter-productive? But for your peace of mind, it's all within a namespace.

Comment: @SF. You use a global in "thousands upon thousands [of] places"? Holy hannah I'm so sorry to hear that ;(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: THAT is what globals exist for. You have 1-3 globals per your whole application, even enormous one, and you keep in them things that are *needed everywhere*, to save up time spent on jumping through hoops to access that. Do you have any better use for global variables? Or did you learn at school that they are obsolete and should never ever be used?

Comment: @SF. This is absolutely _not_ "what globals exist for"; I have no idea where you got that idea from. Globals exist for legacy reasons from the days before encapsulation. Nowadays there is no need for them at all (except for constants initialised from literals, for which I won't make the same claim). It's not because I "learnt it at school"; it's because I am a professional senior developer and know that it is true from experience.

Comment: Globals exist from a time when dynamic allocation was too expensive to be used. There's no justification for user-mode process-globals today.

Answer (score 7):

This is what pointers are for.
Set one to `nullptr` until it points to something that exists.

Or, alternatively, investigate `boost::optional`.

Even better, do away with this global altogether.
You can *already* see the problems/mess it's making in your code!

Comment: Just out of curiosity - in case like this (global_config) what would you suggest? Sometimes global variable is dead simple solution in contrast to passing this as an argument to every single function that needs access to those settings.

Comment: What would be the syntax of the nullptr for initializing the reference like that?

Comment: @SF. I said pointer. You don't/can't/shan't initialise references to `nullptr`.

Comment: @AdrianLis: Without knowing your architecture I couldn't possibly say. But it sounds like a lazy hack that's going to cause you problems later on. What happened to classes?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I am not the OP. What classes do you mean? I hope you don't think about Singleton because this is nothing more than a global in disguise adding some more complexity to achieve pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'd really rather not write `configClass::Instance()->["key"]` a thousand times, when I can write config["key"] instead. If you want to call clean, simple code a lazy hack, please, but I'd rather seek problems with the algorithm, not resolve ones coming from overly complex syntax.

Comment: @AdrianLis: No, not a singleton... A normal class. Pass config into your other classes at construction time. As for not being the OP well regardless you asked me the question ;p

Comment: @SF. If you are calling that "a thousand times" then something is already very wrong and should be fixed before you do anything else.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Let's see: several hundred classes, each of them would need to be initialized with the config, and hold the config field, not to mention passing it from the top level class all the way down the tree, and updating that tree in case config changes live. Do you see any advantages over the global?

Comment: @SF.: Why do you have "several hundred classes"? Refer to my previous comment. You're trying to justify a poor decision by invoking a poor design.

Comment: @SF. The fact that doing this would be hard proves that your design is broken. You should not have several hundred classes depending on a config. That makes it a God object.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Considering the project is some hundred thousand lines by now, would you prefer fewer gargantuan classes? As for 'god object' - I could split the config into multiple smaller ones. This would increase overhead, confuse users and complicate the config interface. I don't think there would be any actual profit.

Comment: Course in basic software design and project management required.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I guess the guys from Mozilla have no clue about software design, with their about:config system... Or Microsoft, for that matter, with the system registry.

Comment: @SF. ...and precisely zero of those are implemented with thousands of calls to C++ globals in hundreds of classes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, they are implemented with millions of calls in hundreds of thousands of classes, to instance of the god config class instead. Which is a hardly more than a semantic difference.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: `MyBranch = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService).getBranch("myBranch"); value = Branch.getIntPref("path.to.key");` Looks to me like `Components` is a god object.

Comment: @SF It's a lot more like a namespace.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: A globally accessible all-encompassing static class, singleton, namespace or complex variable, different feathers on the same animal.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the needs of your config class, one option could be for `configClass` to contain its own `init()` method. Then you can initialize the reference immediately (as required by the language), and call `global_config.init();` from the `init()` method in your question.